# Array multidimensional como retirar um carácter de um determinado index?

Tags: php, array, csv

O código abaixo é resultado da leitura de um arquivo CSV, que o transformo em Array para trata-lo para criar um novo CSV pra poder ser importado com um novo formato. Quero retirar os - que estão nos números de telefone / celular.

Sabemos que nos telefones / celulares existem sempre 4 dígitos antes do -, mas não sei como faze-lo para retirar.

Exemplo:

```
array
  0 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string 'Nome/Razão Social'
      1 => string 'Nome Fantasia'
      2 => string 'Tel.'
      3 => string 'Cel.'
  1 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string 'XXX XXXXX XXXXXXXX'
      1 => string ''
      2 => string '9123-4321'
      3 => string '7123-4312'
```

Obrigado desde já pela ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

Da forma como está, basta você usar o `str_replace`:

```
    $array = [
        ['Nome/Razão Social', 'Nome Fantasia', 'Tel.', 'Cel.'],
        ['XXX XXXXX XXXXXXXX','', '9123-4321', '7123-4312']
    ];

    $array[1] = str_replace("-", "", $array[1]); // alteração feita aqui

    print_r($array);
```